# Extracting some text from HTML using PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find and edit comment element of html with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328631/find-and-edit-comment-element-of-html-with-php)

Hello. Regular expressions in general are way over my head. The answer to my question should be fairly simple, but after digging around for a while I'm still at loss for one. How can I extract "Orange County, CA" using preg_match() in PHP from this HTML excerpt?:

```
<!-- CLTAG GeographicArea=Orange County, CA -->
```

Note that the text in this area will be variable and thus the regular expression needs to be dynamic to account for this.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Can the HTML comment take any other form (apart from the variable text after the `=`) or will it only ever be exactly like this?

Comment: Nope, aside from after the "=", always the same.

Comment: I can't help you with preg_match() in PHP but there is a RegExp() function in Javascript that takes dynamic regular expressions...Maybe it could help.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case it would have to be PHP.

Comment: Modify the XPath in the linked duplicate to `//comment()[contains(., "CLTAG GeographicArea=")]'`. Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One regex you can use would be this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/<!-- CLTAG GeographicArea=(.*?) -->/', $html, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

If there are multiple such comments in the HTML, use `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: @Kobie: I tested it, and it works for me. Double-check that your question matches your *actual* situation.

Comment: Ahh. Figured it out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

regular expression:

```
preg_match('#\<\-\-(.*)\=(.*)\-\-\>#', $html, $matches);
$matches[1] //contain data
```

Comment: The issue is that I need the "CLTAG GeographicArea=" included as well.