# php simpleXMLElement to array: null value

Tags: php, xml, associative-array

I've got following XML:

```
<account>
    <id>123</id>
    <email></email>
    <status>ACTIVE</status>
</account>
```

I want to have it as an array variable. Therefore I read it with `$xml = simplexml_load_file()`. The simplest way to convert simpleXMLElement to an associative array I know is to grind it with: `json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml),1);`

The problem is that I don't want to get the `email` key as an empty array, but rather as a `NULL` value. As SimpleXMLElement, it looks like:

```
public 'email' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[205]
```

whereas in array it looks like:

```
'email' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

I'd like to get:

```
'email' => NULL
```

The only way to achieve this I thought of is iterate through all elements and replace empty array with null value. The problem is that my XML is way bigger (above is just to explain the problem) and I'd have to iterate a lot of XML elements (and this would be manual work - I'm looking for something automatic). Maybe I'm missing some options in one of the functions... or maybe there's another trick to do this?

Comment: The problem is, `email` isn't null. It's empty. To have it null the xml should be `<email />`

Comment: @webnoob That's right! :) But unfortunately you'll still won't get the expected `NULL`

Comment: @hek2mgl - Ah Ok, I assumed it would :(. Ok, another idea. Load the XML into a string, use some regex to strip out the tags that don't have values and then parse it. If they are not there, you can treat them as null.

Comment: @webnoob Will get messy when the xml grows. also you'll have to change the regex for each xml format. I'm currently thinking about a SAX parser. This would save the OP from foreach loops in php. The looping would be done in C code of the extension. Also it should be faster than the json_decode/json_encode approach

Comment: Hmm, good points. Although, I have to ask the question to the OP on why `null` value is so important. Why not check for `""`. Could even have a helper function to do it for you ...

Comment: Guys, thank you for the tip with <email /> - i'll correct it.

@webnoob: the null value is important, because the PHP layer is a part of a bigger project, where we communicate using thrift protocol and we send request using arrays. I would like the XML null value to be represented as PHP null inside nested array - or somethinkg like that ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm afraid that the SAX parser idea won't be easier/lighter than iterating arrays in foreach.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz I've tested it using a SAX parser. I've used the rss feed from *this* site. It took almost the same as the json_decode approach (0.025 sec) meaning, that it should be really faster than using foreach.. but this has to be tested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot add a comment, but I think this will work for you, it should be faster then a regex or a loop:

```
//after you json_encode, before you decode
$str = str_replace(':[]',':null',json_encode($array));
```

An empty array in JSON is represented by "`[]`". Sometimes the arrays are parsed as objects, in that case (or as a fallback) you can replace "`:{}`" too.

Comment: So the overall result of what I want would be:
`json_decode(str_replace(':[]',':null',json_encode($array)))` - sounds like a good idea

Comment: It should be `"email":{}` instead of `"email":[]` but anyway thanks for your idea

Answer (score 1):

An empty [`SimpleXMLElement object`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)  will be casted to an empty array. You can change this by by extending from SimpleXMLElement and implementing the [`JsonSerializable interface`](http://php.net/class.jsonserializable) and casting an it to **null**.

```
/**
 * Class JsonXMLElement
 */
class JsonXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement implements JsonSerializable
{

    /**
     * Specify data which should be serialized to JSON
     *
     * @return mixed data which can be serialized by json_encode.
     */
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $array = array();

        // json encode attributes if any.
        if ($attributes = $this->attributes()) {
            $array['@attributes'] = iterator_to_array($attributes);
        }

        // json encode child elements if any. group on duplicate names as an array.
        foreach ($this as $name => $element) {
            if (isset($array[$name])) {
                if (!is_array($array[$name])) {
                    $array[$name] = [$array[$name]];
                }
                $array[$name][] = $element;
            } else {
                $array[$name] = $element;
            }
        }

        // json encode non-whitespace element simplexml text values.
        $text = trim($this);
        if (strlen($text)) {
            if ($array) {
                $array['@text'] = $text;
            } else {
                $array = $text;
            }
        }

        // return empty elements as NULL (self-closing or empty tags)
        if (!$array) {
            $array = NULL;
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

Then tell `simplexml_load_string` to return an object of `JsonXMLElement` class

```
$xml = <<<XML
<account>
   <id>123</id>
   <email></email>
   <status>ACTIVE</status>
</account>
XML;

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'JsonXMLElement');

// print_r($obj);

print json_encode($obj, true);

/*
 * Output...
{
   "id": 123,
   "email": null,
   "status": "ACTIVE"
}
*/
```

Credit: [hakre](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-i/)

Answer (score 0):

**Check performance str_replace vs recursive loop**

- *Iterations*: 100000
- *XML length*: 4114 bytes
- *Init script time*: ~1.2264486691986E-6 seconds
- *JSON encode/decode time*: ~9.8956169957496E-5 seconds
- **str_replace** average time: **0.00010692856433176** seconds
- **recursive loop** average time: **0.00011844366600813** seconds

The str_replace quickly on ~0.00001 seconds. The difference will be noticeable in many calls